# OpenVPN daemon keeps my harddrives spinning on NAS home server

Tags: hard-disk, openvpn, daemon, nas

I have a home NAS server with OpenVPN daemon installed, however I want to keep my harddrives in idle mode (so they last longer) when nobody actively uses the VPN or files on the NAS.

OpenVPN daemon prevents that because it keep writing its PID to the file:

```
    root@NAS:~# iotop
Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:         3.80 K/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
  725 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    3.80 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
```

It is very annoying because I can hear the hard drives spinning on/off whole night and I am worried that because of constant turning spinning it will shorten their lifespan.

It is the only process I can see in the iotop using the harddrives so I guess it is the only reason why my harddrives keep spinning constantly  during the night.

Comment: Please do not post code or info as images, it's hard to read and may not be copied or searched for using standard engines. Apart from that: It sounds like the system itself runs on some sort of SSD or alike. Any option to dump the logs there and move them to the NAS only once a day?

Comment: I can't read anything in that strip of screenshot. Please [paste it as text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: You can always click on that and see it in full size. I cannot paste it as a text because it appers only for a split second and I cannot copy it that fast, here is direct img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0VKz.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid` option writes the PID just once, at process startup. On the other hand, the `--status /run/openvpn/server.status 10` option writes the status file every 10 seconds.

However, both of these are being written to a RAM-based filesyste, `/run`. It might be that the logging is what's catching you; messages are typically written to files under `/var/log` and I would suggest it's most likely that it's these which are keeping your disks awake.

> **`--daemon [progname]`** Become a daemon after all initialization functions are completed.  This option will cause all message and error output to be sent to the syslog file (such  as `/var/log/messages`) [...] If one of the `--log` options is present, it will supersede syslog redirection.

And later,

> **`--log file`** Output logging messages to file, including output to *stdout*/*stderr* which is generated by called scripts. If file already  exists  it  will  be  truncated. This option [...] will supersede syslog output if `--daemon` or `--inetd` is also specified
>
> **`--log-append file`** Append logging messages to file. If file does not exist, it will be created. This option behaves exactly like `--log` except that it appends to rather than truncating the log file.

If you are happy to forego logging, I would imagine that you could use `--log-append /dev/null` and this would allow your disks to sleep. On the other hand, you shouldn't be getting much logging in the first place; it would be worth identifying what OpenVPN is writing to keep the disks awake. `lsof` could be useful for that:

```
# As root
watch -n1 'lsof -f -p $(pidof openvpn | tr " " ,) 2>&1 | grep -v /lib/'
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot that /run is RAM based. So how would I find out which daemon is actually causing disk writes/read if not iotop ? My distro is Debian.

Comment: @Welite I've extended my answer for you